# What does a linear trend in residual plot mean?

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals

[image]

Above is my residual plot.  My model has only linear terms (no polynomial or interaction terms).  How should I interpret this linear trend in the residual plot?  How should I interpret the high values clustered near Fitted Values ~= 0?

Here's another more exaggerated example:
[image]

Comment: What are your data? Are they discrete & able to take on only certain values (eg integers)?

Comment: The data are the changes in price of a commodity at some fixed unit time in the future. In other words, my regression is y ~ X, for some large predictor matrix X. p(t) is the price at time t; and y(t) = p(t + tau) - p(t), for some fixed length of time time tau.  y > 0 means the price will move up tau in the future. And y < 0 means that the price will move down tau in the future.

Comment: Are the prices discrete?

Comment: They are measured to the nearest .01, yes.

Comment: These plots have no linear trend whatsoever (by construction).  What do you mean by "linear trend," then?

Comment: I mean the negatively slopping line of points. In the second plot, it starts at about (-0.1, 0.15) and ends around (0.9, -0.1).